# convert xml to sorted dictionary

Tags: c#, xml

i have an xml file similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <resource key="123">foo</resource>
    <resource key="456">bar</resource>
    <resource key="789">bar</resource>

</data>
```

i want to put this into a Dictionary (sorted) as key value pairs.
i.e: 
123:foo,
456:bar...etc

the keys are unknown.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
string s = "<data><resource key=\"123\">foo</resource><resource key=\"456\">bar</resource><resource key=\"789\">bar</resource></data>";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(s);
XmlNodeList resources = xml.SelectNodes("data/resource");
SortedDictionary<string,string> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string,string>();
foreach (XmlNode node in resources){
   dictionary.Add(node.Attributes["key"].Value, node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Ah, great minds think alike.  My version's quite a bit more concise, but the approach is the same.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a job for Linq to Xml

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        XDocument yourDoc = XDocument.Load("the.xml");
        var q = from c in yourDoc.Descendants("resource")
                orderby (int) c.Attribute("key")
                select c.Attribute("key").Value + ":" + c.Value;

        foreach (string s in q)
            Console.WriteLine(s);                            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually easier without using Linq and just using an `XmlDocument`:

```
SortedDictionary<string, string> myDict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
foreach (XmlElement e in myXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/data/resource"))
{
   myDict.Add(e.GetAttribute("key"), e.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ:

Load the document `XDocument.Load` or `XDocument.Parse`:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(...);
```

Iterate through the ordered sequence:

```
var sequence = from e in xml.Root.Elements() 
               let key = (string)e.Attribute("key")
               order by key
               select new { 
                 Key = key, 
                 Value = (string)e 
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with XSLT transformation. Do you need to do the job with C#? If not you can simply make a XSLT document which parses through all resource tags and outputs key:value sorted out for you. Very easy accomplished. Is this a solution you want?

Comment: And what do you do with the transform output? You still have to get that into a dictionary.

Comment: You can output it however you want. HTML, TXT, up to you. Right?

Comment: but no form of XSLT output implements IDictionary

Comment: oh I didnt know there was a special dictionary implementation. =)

Comment: @anakata It is trivial to generate C# (or any other language) source code with XSLT. So, one could generate the code that defines the dictionary and adds the key-value pairs to it. ChrisAD is correct that the best tool that is especially designed for tree-transformations is XSLT.