# Create a Dictionary using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, concurrentdictionary

How can I create a `Dictionary` (or even better, a `ConcurrentDictionary`) using Linq?

For example, if I have the following XML

```
<students>
    <student name="fred" address="home" avg="70" />
    <student name="wilma" address="home, HM" avg="88" />
    .
    . (more <student> blocks)
    .
</students>
```

loaded into `XDocument doc;` and wanted to populate a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Info>` (where the key is the name and `Info` is some class holding address and average. Populating `Info` is not my concern now), how would I do this?

Comment: is "using LINQ" a requirement or a trend?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710193/converting-an-xml-document-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var dict = xDoc.Descendants("student")
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, 
                              x => new Info{ 
                                  Addr=x.Attribute("address").Value,
                                  Avg = x.Attribute("avg").Value });


var cDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Info>(dict);
```

Comment: If `ConcurrentDictionary` is a must, it might be better to skip `.ToDictionary` and to load the sequence directly into an empty `ConcurrentDictionary` in a `foreach` loop. This will avoid creating a `Dictionary` (`dict`) that gets thrown away.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will do:

```
var dict = xml.Descendants("student")
              .ToDictionary(r => (string)r.Attribute("name").Value, r => CreateInfo(r));
```

This produced just a usual `Dictionary`; you can construct a `ConcurrentDictionary` [from the usual `Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287236.aspx).

---

Edit: changed `Element` to `Attribute`, thanks to @spender for noticing this. And "student" -> "students", thanks to @Jaroslaw.

Comment: @Jaroslaw: no, actually -- is there a problem? If yes, you can help to improve the answer (or give your own one).

Comment: just run this if you have time, so yo'll get an error. I don't see the point of pasting the exception in the comment. This is only the tip for you to take a look, for me it can stay as is.

Comment: @Jaroslaw: I have got no compiler at hand. The point would be helping the readers to know the right answer, of course.

Comment: Hmm. Why so cryptic, @Jaroslaw? In the mean time, I'd suggest reading an Attribute value rather than child Element value.

Comment: @Vlad: ok, one more left, replace `xml.Descendants("students")` with `xml.Descendants("student")` at it gives more nodes not just the main one.